# Is there a way to open Chrome Dev tools to a new window right away?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

Anyone know of a way to open Chrome Dev tools to a new window upon open?

I know that I can click F12 and then click the 'customize' button and change orientation or pop out the dev tools window.  But that's an extra step, and often a window resize is necessary, and when you do it 50 times a day, it gets to be tedious.

Also, sometimes, on pages I'm testing, pressing F12 will change the layout of the elements on the page and even popping out the dev tools leaves the page layout different than before I opened dev tools.  This can make it hard to tell if an element is visible or not, which makes troubleshooting Webdriver more difficult.

Ideally, CTRL+F12 or something to open dev tools as a separate window would be super handy.  (to any Chromium devs that might be listening ;)   But if anyone has another solution, I'd love to hear it.

Answer (score 3):

If you have your DevTools un-docked, the dock mode, size and position of your DevTools window will remain the same as you previously set it. For example, I just set mine to be maximised on my other monitor. Every time I open up DevTools, it's an un-docked, maximised window, and there's no change to the layout of the inspected window other than the fact it's no longer in focus.

You could alternatively launch Chrome using the `--auto-open-devtools-for-tabs` flag, which will automatically open DevTools in the dock mode, size and position you had it previously. You can use:

**Mac:**`/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --auto-open-devtools-for-tabs`

**Windows:** `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --auto-open-devtools-for-tabs`

In WebDriver, you can set flags for how Chrome opens. However, after looking into this further, it turns out Chrome [currently do not support multiple clients connected to the protocol simultaneously](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/debugger-protocol#simultaneous).

As for speeding things up, you can switch between dock positions with <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> (Mac) or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> (Windows). This toggles between the last two modes you have used, so say you have it docked at the bottom, you then pop it out, using the shortcut now will toggle between the two.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, although this doesn't quite work for me.  I usually have Chrome open and Dev tools in a separate window/monitor.  But when I run a Webdriver/Selenium/Junit test, my new Chrome window opens and runs the test.  If I hit a breakpoint on a problem line, I go to the open Chrome window, hit F12 and Dev tools opens docked on the right.  If I press Ctrl+Shift+D that just toggles between the bottom position and the right position.  It does not actually pop out the dev tools window.

Comment: And just to clarify, if I just have Chrome open with dev tools in a separate window, then open a new window, go to a page, then press F12, it DOES open in a new window like I want.  But there must be something unique about the way that Eclipse/Webdriver/Selenium/Junit opens a new browser window for a test that is causing this behavior.

Comment: @Atom999 Interesting. You could try using the flag I mentioned earlier but set it in the WebDriver config to open DevTools up automatically. First make sure the DevTools last set mode is undocked, then close Chrome and run your tests and see if it opens directly un-docked?

Comment: Thanks. I added that arg to our existing code.

`public RemoteWebDriver createDriver(ChromeDriverService svc)
        {
        ChromeOptions opts = new ChromeOptions();
        long newVal = new Date().getTime();
        opts.addArguments("--user-agent=" + newVal);
        opts.addArguments("--auto-open-devtools-for-tabs");
        DesiredCapabilities caps = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
        caps.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, opts);
        return new ChromeDriver(svc, caps);
        }`

The window opens/closes right away, "Cannot read property 'click' of null

Comment: @Atom999 It turns out after a deeper look, you can't do this because they both use the debugging protocol, and it only allows connection at a time. See [Simultaneous protocol clients](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/debugger-protocol#simultaneous).

Comment: Ahh.. right on. Thanks for trying to help here.  Let's hope Chromium devs add a way to do this in the future.

Comment: @Atom999 I'll look into what is involved. I might be able to create an issue and submit a pull request with a new shortcut.

Comment: Allowing multiple connections is far from trivial. That is the DevTools *most starred* and long-awaited functionality for a reason. It requires a lot of internal plumbing to change to accommodate that. This is just a catch-22 situation which isn't solvable currently. :/

Comment: @Garbee Oh no I didn't mean that, I mean't just adding F12 + Shift (or similar) to open DevTools in undocked mode straight away. Do you think that is a reasonable idea?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you do it.  On opening the developer tools, with the developer tools window in focus, press F1. This will open a settings page. Check the "Auto-open DevTools for popups".

[image]

Originally documented here -- https://newbedev.com/automatically-open-chrome-developer-tools-when-new-tab-new-window-is-opened.